# modify object with reference to self

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
object = {
    element: {
        prop1: "hello",
        prop2: "world"
    }
}
```

I would like to modify for example `prop2` to something else

I tried

```
object2 = {...object, element: 
    {...element, 
        prop2: 'something'
    }
}
```

But I get

> element is not defined

How can I refer to that `element` within the element itself?

Comment: Try `...object.element` instead of `...element`

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, you're not really modifying the object; you're creating a (depending on the structure, shallow) copy.

Comment: ...object.element rather element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `object.element`:

```js
object = {
    element: {
        prop1: "hello",
        prop2: "world"
    }
}

object2 = {...object, element: 
    {...object.element, 
        prop2: 'something'
    }
}

console.log(object2);
```